# Refreshing UI with GCD

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, refresh, grand-central-dispatch

I have a question that bothers me in iOS coding. First I show the code:

```
[AlinkApi openalinkDevicesGetbyUser:^(AlinkResponse *response) {
    [_delegate sideHomeViewItemClick:self.deviceArray[self.selectedIndex]];
    NSIndexPath *selIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.selectedIndex inSection:0];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.deviceTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selIndex animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
    });
} sucessBlock:^{
} failBlock:^{
}];
```

I need to select a row in tableView, should I do `[self.deviceTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selIndex animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];` in main queue?  And did the code have something wrong? My project sometimes would crash, no any more infomation, only tips is  EXC_BAD_ACCESS, I tried many methods can't find out the reasons, but somebody tell me the reason maybe can be not refresh UI in main queue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should always use the main thread whenever interacting with UIKit.

I’m also concerned about all of those other references to properties of `self` from a background thread, too. You shouldn’t access a property from multiple threads unless either (a) you know the object is thread-safe; or (b) you’ve implemented some synchronization mechanism to make it thread-safe, yourself.